# How to automatically setup group in subdirectory in Linux

Tags: linux, file-ownership

I would like to ensure that in only one particular directory on linux server will have newly-created directory setup particular group?

I.e.:
I have directory `/data` with ownership "user1:global_group" and every new subdirectory should have group ownership the same. Once I create directory by using mkdir `/data/subdir1` under user1 or user2 the ownership is "user1:grp_user1" or "user2:grp_user2".

How can I manage the subdirectory ownership?

Many thanks for any ideas ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `chmod` for that.

Apply this: `chmod g+s directory` on a parent directory. Every newly created file and directory, recursively, will have the group of the parent directory.

So:

```
chgrp target_group target_directory
chmod g+s target_directory
mkdir -p target_directory/subdirectory/another_one
ls -l target_directory/subdirectory/another_one
```

And observe, how `another_one` directory has the desired group.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-R` or `--recursive` option. And try `chgrp --help` first.

Comment: This will, unfortunately, not apply to newly created files and directories.